# Make dictionary iterable inside Python Class

Tags: python, loops, class, iterator

Noob in python class. Try to make iterations inside class. Is there any solution for this problem?

```
# some dict
d_init = {'a': 'a_value', 'b': 'b_value', 'c': 'c_value'}


# class 1
class Store1:
    def __init__(self, input_dict):
        self.class_dict = input_dict


# class 2
class Store2:
    def __init__(self, input_dict):
        self.res = []
        self.class_dict = input_dict
        self.class_list = [self.res.append(self.class_dict[k1]) for k1 in self.class_dict.keys()]



obj1 = Store1(d_init)
print("iter 1 = ", [obj1.class_dict[k] for k in obj1.class_dict.keys()])


obj2 = Store2(d_init)
print("iter 2 = ", obj2.class_list)
```

Output:

```
iter 1 = ['a_value', 'b_value', 'c_value']
iter 2 = [None, None, None]
```

Desired output:

```
iter 1 = ['a_value', 'b_value', 'c_value']
iter 2 = ['a_value', 'b_value', 'c_value']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.class_list = [self.res.append(self.class_dict[k1]) for k1 in self.class_dict.keys()]
```

this right here will just append self.res, so you should return self.res and remove class_list or remove self.res and change your code to

```
self.class_list = [self.class_dict[k1] for k1 in self.class_dict.keys()]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
# class 2
class Store2:
    def __init__(self, input_dict):
        self.class_dict = input_dict
        self.class_list = [self.class_dict[k1] for k1 in self.class_dict]
        # or
        self.class_list = list(self.class_dict.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding list comprehensions-

```py
self.class_list = [self.res.append(self.class_dict[k1]) for k1 in self.class_dict.keys()]
```

This will store a list of the *result of `.append`* inside `self.class_list` (and `.append` will obviously return `None`). The actual values are appended to `self.res` as you commanded it to do. If you printed `obj2.res` instead you would have gotten your desired result.

If you want the dict values to be in `class_list`, why are you appending to a different list altogether? why not just-

```py
self.class_list = [self.class_dict[k1] for k1 in self.class_dict.keys()]
```

Even better, all those list comprehensions to get the values from a dict can easily be simplified to-

```py
list(self.class_dict.values())
```

or if you prefer golfing-

```py
[*self.class_dict.values()]
```

Comment: thanks for explanations. I'm planning add filter in list like this:  [self.class_dict[k1] for k1 in self.class_dict.keys() if ....]. Is there a convenient way to use filters with that?   list(self.class_dict.values()) -

Comment: @ecomkalinin yes, you can just `[value for value in self.class_dict.values() if ...]`

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:
Change

```
print("iter 2 = ", obj2.class_list)
```

To
Better answer:

```
print("iter 2 = ", obj2.res)
```

When you use list comprehension, and executing methods inside with iteration's return value. It leaves a None data type, because you shifted output to self.res of class Store2. Hence, [None, None, None].
To make self.class_list equal to self.res of you can do this..

```
# class 2
class Store2:
    def __init__(self, input_dict):
        self.res = []
        self.class_dict = input_dict
        ## run the list comp. after setup of 'res' and 'class_dict'
        [self.res.append(self.class_dict[k1]) for k1 in self.class_dict.keys()]
        ## the local scope of class [None, None, None] value, will be trashed
        ## thanks python, for the dynamic cleanup   :D
        self.class_list = self.res.copy()

obj2 = Store2(d_init)
print("iter 2 = ", obj2.class_list)
```

Output

```
iter 2 = ['a_value', 'b_value', 'c_value']
```

Comment: thank you for advice, I'm just looking to clean up the code to avoid redundand variables